# JavaScript not found [object HTMLSpanElement], how i can fix that

Tags: javascript, html

```js
"use strict";
let btn = document.getElementById("buttonCarrito");
btn.addEventListener("click",agregar);

//this function is agregar (add in English), the idea is that this function put the elements Manzana (Apple) in the shop cart but when i try do this i get [object HTMLSpanElement]50 (50 is the Apple value, but i don't can show only the number 50)
function agregar(){

    let Productos= {
            "Manzana": "50",
            "Banana": "40",
            "Naranja": "30",
            "Mandarina": "20"        
    }

    console.table(Productos)

    let frutaComprada= document.getElementById("inputProducto").value;

    let costoTotal= document.getElementById("valor");
        
    let productoSeleccionado=Productos[frutaComprada];

    costoTotal=costoTotal+productoSeleccionado;

    valor.innerHTML=costoTotal;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Bienvenido a la tienda</h1>
        <input id="inputProducto" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su producto">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="inputCompra" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el valor de su compra">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="buttonCarrito">Agregar al carrito</button>
        <p>El valor total de su compra es: <span id="valor"> 0 </span></p>
        </div>
</body>

<script src="js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: My spanish isn't the best, any chance you want to do a bit more effort translating, and navigating us to where your problem actually is? My idea: `costoTotal` is at least your `valor`, which seems to be a span, but you use it directly (I assume you want to get it as an int there) and then you add a product to it (if the product isn't found that would be your undefined)

Comment: i will take a moment to translate the code, my bad

Comment: The value of products is already being set from the object. Is the second input meant to be quantity, and then you multiply that number by the value in the object? A dropdown list would be really useful here too so you don't have to type in the products manually.

Comment: Possibly it is but it has been 1 week since I started with this language and I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: can you try to set the inner html as valor.innerHTML=`<span>${costoTotal}</span>`;

Comment: Fair enough @ElBartoVIlla :)

Comment: Thanks you Andy, I am new to programming but I am already falling in love with the code and its community. thank you very much to all

Answer (score 1):

1. Values from form inputs will *always* be strings, so to add numbers together you need to coerce the string to a number. A couple of methods: 1) `Number(str)` or 2) `+str`.
2. Your object of products/prices: there's no need to have those prices as strings.
3. The main problem you were having is that `let costoTotal= document.getElementById("valor");` is only picking up the *element* and not the text content. We can use `let costoTotal= document.getElementById("valor").textContent;` for that, but then we need to coerce that to a number similarly to input values.

(Sidenote: at the moment your code doesn't use the value from `inputCompra` which is why I asked about it in the comments. So the total will increase by 40 for bananas, for example, regardless of what is entered in that input.)

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("buttonCarrito");
btn.addEventListener("click", agregar);

function agregar() {

  let Productos = {
    Manzana: 50,
    Banana: 40,
    Naranja: 30,
    Mandarina: 20
  }

  let frutaComprada = document.getElementById("inputProducto").value;
  let costoTotal = Number(document.getElementById("valor").textContent);
  let productoSeleccionado = Productos[frutaComprada];

  costoTotal = costoTotal + productoSeleccionado;

  valor.textContent = costoTotal;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bienvenido a la tienda</h1>
  <input id="inputProducto" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su producto">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="inputCompra" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el número de artículos">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="buttonCarrito">Agregar al carrito</button>
  <p>El valor total de su compra es: <span id="valor"> 0 </span></p>
</div>
```

Here's a version that uses quantity in case you were curious.

```js
let Productos = {
  Manzana: 50,
  Banana: 40,
  Naranja: 30,
  Mandarina: 20
}

const product = document.getElementById('inputProducto');
const quantity = document.getElementById('inputCompra')
const valor = document.getElementById('valor');
const btn = document.getElementById('buttonCarrito');

btn.addEventListener('click', agregar);

function agregar() {

  const frutaComprada = product.value;
  const itemQuantity = Number(quantity.value);
  const productoSeleccionado = Productos[frutaComprada];
  const subTotal = productoSeleccionado * itemQuantity;
  let costoTotal = Number(valor.textContent);

  costoTotal = costoTotal + subTotal;

  valor.textContent = costoTotal;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bienvenido a la tienda</h1>
  <input id="inputProducto" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su producto">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="inputCompra" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el valor de su compra">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="buttonCarrito">Agregar al carrito</button>
  <p>El valor total de su compra es: <span id="valor"> 0 </span></p>
</div>
```